# click and touchstart event not working on android device

Tags: javascript, android, events, click

I have written a web app, hosted on a remote server.
on my desktop computer it's working fine.
on my android device however there is a click event, which does not fire.
I also added a jquery touchstart event, but to no avail.
I want to mention that the respective Html element is created dynamically.
Any suggestions?
thanx for your help.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-bind-touchstart-and-click-events-but-not-respond-to-both/